# locationManager and data managing

Tags: json, swift, asynchronous, ibeacon, alamofire

I'm writing an application to scan iBeacon devices and fetch from database data related to beacons using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON. My problem is devices are scanned every second and I want to keep actual tableview of beacons in range. For example when I lose couple of beacons in the same time I get array index out of boundary error.

```
    func locationManager(locationManager: KTKLocationManager!, didRangeBeacons beacons: [AnyObject]!) {
    let knownBeacons = beacons.filter{ $0.proximity != CLProximity.Unknown }
    let group = dispatch_group_create()

    dispatch_group_enter(group)
    deleteFromFoundBeacons(knownBeacons)
    dispatch_group_leave(group)

    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        if (knownBeacons.count > 0) {
            self.addToFoundBeacons(knownBeacons)
        }
    })

    tableView.reloadData()
}

    func addToFoundBeacons(knownBeacons: [AnyObject]!) {
    for i in 0..<knownBeacons.count {
        var isOnList = false
        let foundBeacon = knownBeacons[i] as! CLBeacon
        for j in 0..<Equipments.count {
            if (knownBeacons[i].minor == Equipments[j].minor) {
                isOnList = true
            }
        }
        if (isOnList == false) {
            httpProtocol.makeGetRequestForEquipment(foundBeacon.minor) { equipment in
                if let equipment = equipment {
                    self.Equipments.append(equipment)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func deleteFromFoundBeacons(knownBeacons: [AnyObject]!) {
    for i in 0..<Equipments.count {
        var isToDelete = true
        for j in 0..<knownBeacons.count {
            if (knownBeacons[j].minor == Equipments[i].minor) {
                isToDelete = false
            }
        }
        if (isToDelete) {
            Equipments.removeAtIndex(i)
        }
    }
}
```

Adding new beacons to Equipments (and tableview) works correctly, but when any of beacons leave scanning range then error shows up. My question is how to make beacon management independend from locationManager function which is called every second?

These are methods for tableView:

```
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Equipments.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("EquipmentTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EquipmentTableViewCell

    let equipment = Equipments[indexPath.row]

    cell.equipmentLabel.text = equipment.name
    cell.equipmentPhoto.image = equipment.photo

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Can you show your methods implementations that return the count of items in the tableView and the specific item in each?

Comment: @davidgyoung See edited post

Comment: Why does the code call deleteFromFoundBeacons before the call to addToFoundBeacons?

Comment: @davidgyoung I wanted after a new scan first to delete beacons from table view which are out of range and then add new ones which are in the scanning range. Maybe the name of the method is not good, but this method deletes from Equipments every object whose minor is not found in the actual scan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding another if statement to check whether `i < Equipments.count` in `deleteFromFoundBeacons` before every iteration of the main loop. Thanks to it I also got rid off dispatch section in `locationManager`. I also changed `tableView.reloadData()` to `beginUpdates() - endUpdates()` sections in order to manage table dynamically in every scan.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are getting the exception because the code in `deleteFromFoundBeacons` is removing an item from the array inside a loop that iterates over it.  You can't do that.   You probably need to construct a new array with the beacons you want, and then replace the old array with the new one at the end.

Comment: I haven't thought about that. When I will have a chance I will check it. I think that should work.